# Error: Tarefas.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a one-to-many association between a "Tasks" and another "Employees" model. This error persists.

The code is separated into two models.

Model "Funcionarios":

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize')
const database = require('../db')
const schema = ''
const Tarefas = require('./tarefas')

class Funcionarios extends Sequelize.Model {}

Funcionarios.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    nome: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true // garante que o nome do funcionário seja único na tabela
    },
    cargo: Sequelize.STRING
  },

  {
    sequelize: database,
    modelName: 'Funcionarios',
    timestamps: false,
    schema
  }
)

Funcionarios.hasMany(Tarefas, {
  foreignKey: 'funcionarioId'
})

module.exports = Funcionarios
```

Is there something I missed? The directory is correct.

Comment: Please share other parts of the relationship where you use `Terefas.belongsTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize')
const database = require('../db')
const schema = ''
const Funcionarios = require('./Funcionarios')

class Tarefas extends Sequelize.Model {
  // static associate(models) {
  //   Tarefas.belongsTo(models.Funcionarios, { foreignKey: 'funcionarioId' })
  // }
}

Tarefas.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    nomeTarefa: DataTypes.STRING,
    tipoTarefa: DataTypes.STRING,
    dataInicio: DataTypes.STRING,
    dataFim: DataTypes.STRING,
    descricao: DataTypes.STRING,
    funcionario: DataTypes.STRING,
    aprovador: DataTypes.STRING,
    nivel: DataTypes.STRING,
    participante: DataTypes.STRING
  },

  {
    sequelize: database,
    modelName: 'Tarefas',
    timestamps: false,
    schema
  }
)

Tarefas.belongsTo(Funcionarios, {
  foreignKey: 'funcionarioId'
})

module.exports = Tarefas
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).